# Получить секцию runtime из файла App.config

Tags: c#, .net

Добрый день. Подскажите, как можно получить секцию runtime из файла App.config (необходимо для последующего добавления этой секции в конфиг своего приложения myapp.exe.config на этапе установки приложения).

Пробовал с помощью ConfigurationManager'а. Если по ключу или по имени настройки, то всё хорошо.Например так:

`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["settingkey"];`

А для runtime возвращает null.
Вот часть файла App.config:

```
<appSettings>
 <add key="settingkey" value="7" />
 </appSettings>
 <!--***-->
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
   <dependentAssembly>
    <!--some stuff-->
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Буду признателен за любые советы

Answer (score 2):

К сожалению, в удобном виде получить эту секцию нельзя (например, в виде коллекции ключ-значение, как это сделано для `appSettings`). Cекция `runtime` определена в файле `machine.config` с типом `IgnoreSection`.

```
<section name="runtime" type="System.Configuration.IgnoreSection ... />
```

Никаких полезных операций этот класс не предоставляет.

```
// с объектом runtime, фактически, ничего нельзя сделать
var runtime = (IgnoreSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("runtime");
```

Но можно считать секцию в виде XML-элемента:

```
// ConfigurationUserLevel задает, какой конфигурационный файл нужно открыть
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var configXml = XElement.Load(config.FilePath);

// получаем секцию runtime
var runtimeXml = configXml.Element("runtime");

// получаем секции dependentAssembly
XNamespace ns = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1";
var dependencies = runtimeXml
    .Element(ns + "assemblyBinding")
    .Elements(ns + "dependentAssembly");

foreach (var depAssembly in dependencies) {
    // читаем информацию из элементов assemblyIdentity и bindingRedirect
    var asmIdentity = depAssembly.Element(ns + "assemblyIdentity");
    var name = (string)asmIdentity.Attribute("name");
    var publicKeyToken = (string)asmIdentity.Attribute("publicKeyToken");
    var culture = (string)asmIdentity.Attribute("culture");

    var bindingRedirect = depAssembly.Element(ns + "bindingRedirect");
    var oldVersion = (string)bindingRedirect.Attribute("oldVersion");
    var newVersion = (string)bindingRedirect.Attribute("newVersion");
}
```

Comment: Как вы считаете конфиг в XElement - там же декларация есть в начале?

Comment: @PavelMayorov метод Load пропускает декларацию и читает сразу корень.

Comment: @PavelMayorov достаточно подключить пространство имён System.Xml.Linq

Comment: @kvm к сожалению от считывает настройки из myapp.exe.config, а мне нужно из app.config проекта..

Comment: @AndrewFedotov ну так и читайте из app.config - это ж еще проще...

Comment: @PavelMayorov я ничего кроме System.Configuration.IgnoreSection не получаю.. покажите как это сделать?

Comment: @AndrewFedotov **грр!** Вы чем ответ читали-то?

Comment: @PavelMayorov если вы про это
 `var runtime = (IgnoreSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("runtime");` 
то ничего полезного не получаю

Comment: @AndrewFedotov а зачем вы так написали? Прочитайте ответ еще раз.